# Android custom image view using built-in attributes

Tags: android

It's my very first question here, so please go easy on me ;)

1. I've built my custom `View` class extending `ImageView`.

   ```
   public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. I have created a set of custom parameters for it in the shape of a `<declare-styleable>` item in the `attrs.xml` file.

   ```
   <declare-styleable name="CustomImageView">
       <attr name="angle" format="integer"/>
   </declare-styleable>
   ```
3. I've figured out how to access (i.e. read from within the class and set from within the layout) these values.

   ```
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomImageView, 0, 0);

   try {
       a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomImageView_angle, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
   ```

   So far, so easy. All of the above are directly taken from the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).

However, I could not figure out how to access the inherited attributes of the `ImageView` class. Specifically, I want to read what was set as the `src` attribute of the `ImageView`. I'm assuming I have to use a different value for the second parameter of the `obtainStyledAttributes(...)` call, but I don't know what to use there and this obviously does not work:

```
a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ImageView, 0, 0);
```

So, how do I access the built-in attributes of my super class?
How do I get the int value (drawable res id) that was set for the `android:src` attribute?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at what can you get from the "super" pointer?

Comment: Yes. There is a `getDrawable()` method, but it returns a `Drawable` object, not the int resource id. There is also a `setImageResource(int)` method - which does exactly the opposite of what I want. The equivalent `getImageResource()` does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the int value (drawable res id) that was set for the
>   android:src attribute?

Use `getAttributeResourceValue` to get `id` of `drawable` :

```
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    String android_schemas = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    int srcId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(android_schemas, "src", -1);
}
```

Comment: It looks a little hacky to me, because of all the String literals you put in there instead of having some sort of constants to refer to - but it works as intended. Thanks!